# Looking for title/author of a short story about sailors dying of thirst who enter another world

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, books

I am looking for one particular short story that was in an anthology of sci-fi from the 1960s or 1970s. The title of the story may have been "The Village Green" or something like that.

In it, a group of desperate, dying sailors slip out of the earth into some other dimension/reality: an unformed world where at first there is only a stream and some breadfruit trees, but slowly their collective imagination fleshes out the world.  I think that only their distance from other people allowed them to slip away.

Another thing I remember is that one of the men, named Kruger, doesn't quite make it all the way and remains a disembodied spirit of sorts in the new world, plagued by thirst.  Eventually the protagonist makes his way back to Earth, where he is still thirsty.

Does anyone remember this story?   I want to read it again but can't remember the author or exact title...

Comment: @ImaginaryEvents - My first thought was Fiddler's Green (Kruger is not exactly a common name). That said, we don't vote to close Story-ID questions unless they're confirmed by the OP.

Comment: As @ImaginaryEvents noted, this is ["Fiddler's Green"](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?69796) by Richard McKenna. You probably read it in Damon Knight's anthology [*Orbit 2*](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?25114).

Comment: Meta policy is not to close as duplicate unless both questions have confirmation from their respective askers, i.e. acceptance or comments.

Comment: @Jonah and others, An answer can't be accepted until an answer is given. The story is indeed Fiddler's Green. I've already guiltily answered another question where the answer had already been given in comments, so please could someone else answer this one!

Comment: Thanks folks, it is indeed Fiddler's Green.  It wasn't the greatest story, but not know what it was had bugged me.  Thanks!